# How to select count and use where with Laravel's fluent query builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

in my case

```
$products = $products->select(array('products.*', \DB::raw('COUNT(extra_fields.price) as price_count')))->leftJoin('extra_fields', 'products.id', '=', 'extra_fields.item_id')
                    ->where('item_type', 'App\Models\Product')
                    ->whereRaw("price = '0'")
                    ->whereRaw("price_count = 1")
                    ->groupBy('item_id')
                    ->groupBy('price')

                ;
```

when i want to use { price_count } in where or whereRaw i got :

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'price_count'
```

price_count just only work on this way :

```
->orderBy('price_count')
```

how can i use price_count on where or whereRaw ?

any advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`havingRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) as:

```
->havingRaw('price_count = 1')
```

OR

```
->having('price_count', '=', 1)
```

OR

> The `havingRaw` method may be used to set a raw string as the value of the `having` clause.

```
->havingRaw('COUNT(extra_fields.price) = 1')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use summary function value as you want, instead of "where" you can use in "having".

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use summary function value as you want, instead of "where" you can use in "having".

You can use [`havingRaw`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) as:

```
->havingRaw('price_count = 1')
```

OR

```
->having('price_count', '=', 1)
```

OR

```
->havingRaw('COUNT(extra_fields.price) = 1')
```